# ArchLinux Xfce4 - NetworkManager keeps asking for password

Tags: networking, arch-linux, xfce, eee-pc, networkmanager

I've recently installed ArchLinux with Xfce4 and NetworkManager on an Eeepc 1005HA.
NetworkManager is mostly fine - it auto-connects to ethernet and will auto-connect for wifi too if the connection is already set up.

My problem is that it requires a password every time I wish to edit or add connections.  Also when selecting a network from the systray menu it doesn't ask for a network key, so I have to then go and edit it before it will work.

I have tried following https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Set_up_PolicyKit_Permissions but `dbus-launch` breaks my mouse and the `.pkla` file doesn't seem to do anything.

My user is already a member of `wheel` and `network` as well as a good few others, and network-manager-applet is installed.

Hope you can help!

Comment: Turns out I had a typo in my `.plka` file, so I no longer need a password to edit/add/delete.  I'm still not being asked for a wifi key when I select one though...

Comment: Have you tried installing gnome-keyring? I believe it includes the dialog for inputting these network keys/passwords and such.

Comment: I have since changed to using **wicd**, and it works great :)

Comment: @darkblackcorner Please remember to post an answer below and mark it accepted if you think that's an actual answer to your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had typo in my `.plka` file, so the issue is resolved.

I have since switched to using **wicd** instead.